# How do you center a UIPickerView selectedRow?

Tags: ios, alignment, uipickerview

I created a UIPickerView in iOS 9 using initWithFrame.  However, the selected row (shown by a rectangular box) is flush with the bottlm of the frame, and there is a bunch of blank space at the top.

How can I anchor the selectedRow higher on the screen, about halfway in the picker's view bounds?

Other questions on stackoverflow concern horizontal alignment within a cell.  I am asking about vertical alignment of the selectedRow, and keeping it anchored halfway from frame top and bottom regardless of the index while spinning.  This is not a picker in input view; it is one that is always on screen.

Comment: A picture would be helpful. And relevant code for populating your picker view.